# Typescript extend primitive types

Tags: typescript

Is any way to extend primitives like `number` to separate types of different classes?

```
type UserId = number;

class User {
  constructor(
    public id: UserId,
  ) {
      
  }
}

const usersIds: UserId[] = [];
const someUser = new User(1 as UserId);
usersIds.push(someUser.id); // <-- Correct
usersIds.push(2); // <-- Need to throw compile error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgSQCZQLxQHYFcC2ARkgNwBQZAxgDYCGccsCiUA3mVFJQPbZzCJclYN0QAKDpyhhchagEtKUeagBcTJGgA0kgJRtJUqJIC+ZM1V78ouZnDRx18TagDaAXUxQP5Hn2BQcNz4EM4sWNgQAO4a4gCMUPSxaLrktkj2qHAAdDJwABZiQSFh2SqpUAD0lVAAPAC09VAAwqKIEMJk6YiZOXmFAEwV1XWNUAByEBDoIlDA+YjcMTz4YPLU0EiLiEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime there wouldn't be a difference, but at compile time you can use a trick called [branding](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) to make the compiler think that `UserId` extends `number`:

```
type UserId = number & { __userId: true };
```

By [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `number` with an object type, we have defined a type which extends `number` but is not extended  *by* `number`.  Note that

```
const someUser = new User(1 as UserId);
```

is using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to lie to the compiler; `1` is not really a `UserId` according to that definition.  And such lying is necessary because you don't really want to try to add a `__userId` property to a primitive `number` at runtime (you could mess with the `Number` prototype, but this would add such a property to every `number`, which defeats the purpose).

But it serves your needs:

```
usersIds.push(someUser.id); // okay
usersIds.push(2); // error!
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserId'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=77&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgSQCZQLxQHYFcC2ARklAGRQDeUA+tbgiqgFxTCK7QC+A3AFC8BjADYBDOHFgNKvKFAEB7bHDa4BweYgAUM2VDC5CQgJYCoR5pKRoANDoCU0nZ17PBi5VHpI4aOC3hWqADaALqYUKF8CkrAUHDy+BABiOHYEADulloAjFBiWWh2fF6IPqhwAHT6cAAWmvGJyRXmRVAA9G1Q8gDWIiC8JWWV1XUATK0dUEiIGgCEvJMAgogA5gQQ2LHyAGas4NAA5HhESAdmEtjysWJwRivYIobQ6noiiCKJwCQ7e5BQB8k0AcgA)

Comment: Thanks! Branding is perfect for my case.